# How can I distingush between the content property of the ::before element being not specified at all and being specified as an empty string?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-element, getcomputedstyle

How can I check in javascript (with jQuery) if the 'content' property is set on a before or after pseudo element? In chrome, `window.getComputedStyle(elem, '::before').getPropertyValue('content')` returns an empty string both when 'content' is set to an empty string and when content is not set.

I have thought of one solution: set other properties such as width and height and check if the computed style is affected; I would, however, like to minimize the number of calls to getComputedStyle.

Thanks

Comment: If the pseudo element was positioned absolutely, it would have no effect on the width/height of the 'parent'. What is it you are trying to do and why?

Comment: I am writing a script which creates a stylesheet based on the computed style of some elements. I want to skip css rules for before/after pseudo elements if the content attribute was not set.

Comment: Like to show how content is set in your css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an *if truthy* clause to test that it has some value.

E.G:

```
var before = window.getComputedStyle(elem, ':before').getPropertyValue('content');
if(before && before!=="none"){//<-- (IE / FF fix) check it doesn't equal 'none'
    //content: is defined but it could still be an empty string
    alert("Before="+before);
} else {
    //there is no :before content: defined at all
}
```

[Here's the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Le1tLbda/9/). Try changing the css `:before` content to test it.

Also, you can reduce the code still further by using 
`getComputedStyle(elem, ':before').content` 
instead of 
`window.getComputedStyle(elem, ':before').getPropertyValue('content')`.

Comment: @torazaburo. Yes, and if you test the fiddle you'll see it *does* distinguish between these.

Comment: @torazaburo Are you trying the demo fiddle? Here's a version with 3 tests (content, empty content and no content): http://jsfiddle.net/Le1tLbda/7/

Comment: Strange, this solution worked even though it failed the first time I tried it. There must have been a bug in my code that I failed to notice at the time.

Comment: Ah, here is the peculiarity that confused me: http://jsfiddle.net/hrmvs98d/ 
When the content is an empty string, quotes will be added to the computed content property, but when content is set to a non-empty string, quotes will not be added to the computed content property.

Comment: This method fails in FF and IE when `content` is **not set** or set to **none** (without quotes!). Both return string 'none' in both cases. See my answer below.

Comment: @MartinErnst Thanks. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Opera have a bug with getComputedStyle() for PseudoElements:

When the style of `#elem::before` is set to `{display: none;}` or `{content: none}` or when the content is just **not set**, both return the computed style of #elem.

But in practise it's no problem: A PseudoElement with `display: none` ore no content will not be displayed, so you **must** set content to show it.

In **css** content must be **quoted**:

```
div::before { content: "something"}   or { content: "" } // empty string.
```

When you now retrieve .getComputedStyle(...).content you get not an empty string but a **string with two quotes** in it. That way you can distinguish your both cases.

Take care when using the content value in **javascript**, it must be **doublequoted**.

As in CSS3 specified content can explicitely set to "nothing":

```
#elem::before { content: none } // without quotes!
```

In this case FF and IE returns **none**, Chrome and Opera really nothing.

[JSFidlle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dazyc0fp/28/) to test all cases.

Comment: can you provide a link to the bugtracker or something that supports this claim?

Comment: @Woodrow Barlow. Sorry, I can't. I'm working on a jQuery plugin that will enable the control of PseudoElements with javascript. My answer reflects my experience I made with this topic (and it's **not all** experience, targeting Safari is horrible!).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `window.getMatchedCSSRules`, then looking through the rules:

```
function hasBeforeContentProperty(elt) {
    return [].some.call(
        window.getMatchedCSSRules(elt, '::before'),
        function(rule) {
            return /content/.test(rule.cssText);
        }
    );
}
```

This needs some bullet-proofing and sanity testing, but the concept is find the rules applicable to the `::before` pseudo-element, then examine their `cssText` property to see if a content is specified, whether as empty string or otherwise. Note that you need to do the textual scan of `rule.cssText` instead of looking at `rule.style.content`, since the latter will always be the empty string even if rule does not specify content.

Answer (score -1):

You need to  use a real DOM element instead of a pseudo one. You can't modify pseudo elements through JavaScript, is not a DOM element

Comment: I am creating stylesheets based on the computed style of the passed in elements and placing clones of the elements in an iframe where the computed styles are applied. I need only to generate additional stylesheets.